Suggestions don't appear properly in Visual Studio Code
I have problem with suggestions in Visual Studio Code during coding some game. Whenever I see a tutorial on Youtube, all developers have those auto-suggestions working properly, like when they type for example Input., they receive instantly Godot methods, while when I use my Visual Studio Code, and I'm trying to do this, I get the message "no suggestions." when for example i try to find the method is_key_pressed() while typing Input.is_ (Hotkey for ctrl + spacebar).
I saw a couple of tutorials about "how to configure Visual Studio Code for Godot" but none of them raise the subject. Tried to google out this topic, but without any result as well. Maybe I am dumb or something, but can not find the solution.
Could you help me with this?
#Edit
I have all needed Extensions: C#, C# Dev Kit, C# Tools for Godot, and language mode is set to a C#

Maybe these might help:
Using Godot + C# + Visual Studio Code
How To Use Visual Studio AND VS Code With Godot 4
How to Use VS Code with Godot
It's difficult to pin point why your suggestions aren't showing but if you've followed the solution by @Malcolm Mutare it should work, If not maybe try restarting the editor or maybe even your computer?
